# Make image responsive on Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using bootstrap and Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I created a field of image, but image is not responsive. Can anybody help and have any suggestions how can I edit this code to make image responsive on small screens.

Link to my website: http://vizionstar.co.uk/global_listings/

And here is my code which I'm using to get the image from front-page.php:

```
if(get_field('testimonial_content')) {
    echo '<div class="info-box-container">';

    $image = get_field('Image');
          $size = 'full'; 

          if( $image ) {

            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size ); 
          }

    echo '<h3>' . get_field('testimonial_title') . '</h3>';
    echo '<h1>' . get_field('testimonial_title2') . '</h1>';                
    echo '<h1>' . get_field('testimonial_title3') . '</h1>';
    the_field('testimonial_content');
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

The image is on testimonials section "WHAT THE INDUSTRY SAYS ABOUT US".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add this to your style.css:

```
.info-box img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome :-) Then maybe you want to "accept" my answer so other users with similar problems can find the solution later easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your CSS file

```
img.attachment-full.size-full {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```